# Long-exposure with Raspberry Pi at night

Tags: exposure, long-exposure, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project that requires multiple photos of a specific building at night. I want to set up a webcam and a Rasperry Pi, and set it to take an image every 30 Minutes every night for a few months. From these pictures, I will extract the shape of the building, and calculate the difference in illumination between the building and the background. This doesn't need to be super precise, since I will use averages over time.

I have a Rasperry Pi 3, and am looking to purchase a fitting webcam. There are two common camera modules available, one with, one without IR filter. For night time photography, the IR-Version is usually recommended, but if I understand it correctly, those require IR illumination. Since we are talking about a building, illumination is off the table. Since the amount of light is my entire focus, I do not need the images be good, or even sharp. Just consistent.

Now I have the following questions:

- Does a Non-IR-Filter-Camera make sense for this project, or should I rather stick with the normal camera module?
- The maximum shutter speed for the Raspberry Pi camera module seems to be 6 seconds. I have not found any hardware documents for this, so can anyone confirm this?
- Is this even a viable setup, or am I missing anything fundamental?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a camera as a measuring device, not to produce photos for a creative, artistic, or historical purpose as defined in the group guidelines.

Comment: Just because the building is not being illuminated by IR does not mean it is not emitting IR. If the building is warm enough it will be radiating heat not visible to human vision that will be recorded by some types of IR cameras (depending on exactly the portion of the IR spectrum to which they are sensitive).

Comment: @xiota I would like to estimate the amount of light the building emits over time. Basically, at what time the lights are turned off completely. I'm just the friend asked for tech help, not the actual researcher, but the research question is about light pollution and civil engineering. Multiple devices are to be deployed once we get it to work.

Comment: @MichaelClark per https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5736/are-questions-about-scientific-photography-on-topic it seemed fine here.

Comment: @MichaelClark Reg. the IR-point, that is indeed my question. The non-IR-camera would be affected from IR-heat-noise, since the distribution of heat takes time, while the switching of lights is instant. Thus I would assume the standard version of the camera should be more precise?

Comment: @phi That one meta post, in which several newcomers all seem to be upvoting each others' opinions needs to be balanced with other meta discussions such as [Are questions about industrial optics on topic?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1858/15871) and [Is photography for technical documentation and/or measurement off topic?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5358/15871) and [Why are printers, earplugs, and shoes on topic, but not video, graphic editing, or computer vision?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5589/15871)

Comment: Matt's answer to [Why are printers, earplugs, and shoes on topic, but not video, graphic editing, or computer vision?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5589/15871) is perhaps the most succinct and right to the point statement on the line of reasoning many of the well established members of this community have concerning what this community should be about.

Comment: @phi My issue with the question is that the goal is to determine when the lights are turned off and how much (visible) light is emitted by a building. Those interested in the project have no concern at all if their project produces photographs or not, they just want to find a way to answer the question: How much light does this building emit? Perhaps a conventional camera is not even the instrument best suited for that job?

Comment: This also doesn't fit under the _other_ test in that meta question: _Does the question fall within the area of expertise of photographers?_ No, not really: you're looking at cheap webcams, not cameras made for taking photographs, and your particular interest is in qualities of those cameras basically unrelated to the photo-making qualities.

Comment: We aren't saying this to be difficult, just... maybe you're looking at the wrong tool for the job? Why not, say, _a light meter_?

Comment: 6 second exposures seem wildly under. Photography at night in dark places often uses exposures that go into minutes - but I have no idea how you plan to process the image or what you are looking for in it. Heat pollution is an incredible problem (see Phoenix, AZ and heat island effect) - but is this an effect that you want tainting your light pollution? (as you've observed with the IR/nonIR dilemma).

Comment: Whether or not a camera will work for this depends entirely on how you plan to take the image received and attempt to glean insights from it. Please add that info to the question - along with the *why* behind it. Why you're doing it may not seem relevant to your actual question, but it helps sell people on helping you out. This is a community, and like any group of people, providing motivational factors is part of getting people to volunteer. It also just makes things more interesting.

Comment: I would assume a building that emits short wavelength IR (which will pass a glass lens) to be on fire :)

Answer (score 4):

An IR filter reduces a portion of visible light as well. You would do well to ask for the transmission curves at the camera detector with and without the filter. Determine what spectral range you need to cover in your "light" and "background" regions. By example, when you cannot accept that an IR filter will cut 10% of the visible dark red region of your image because you want to include the true color intensity of neon red signs in the images, then you have your answer.

Since you seem to be analyzing results over longer time frames (hours) compared to the image capture time (six seconds), take snapshot clusters. By example, take a series of 10 - 100 six second images each hour. Average those images to lower the contributions from stray artifacts (e.g. airplanes that fly in and out of the view frame when the camera captures the image) and to average out certain aspects of the image noise.

You will want to test one image of a six second shot to confirm that it captures both the lowest and highest intensity of light you need. When the lowest light you *must* have is not captured *at all*, you will need to increase exposure time or go to a faster lens. When the highest light you expect saturates the image, you will need either to lower exposure time or add a neutral filter (and of course repeat all of the single-shot low light tests).

You will want the image to be in focus. Set the focus during the day and hold it for the night shots. Also, use the day shots to define the "region of interest" precisely in the image analysis software.

Finally, learn what is meant by image processing. At a base level, without even thinking about the hardware, you will have to appreciate red, green, blue channels and how they are combined to gray. Then, you will have to appreciate how the camera sees RGB. A recommendation at this point is to spend time browsing sites devoted to image analysis for science/engineering. This includes sites for programs such as ImageJ (free) or higher end commercial programs such as Igor Pro. Those forums have users who have tackled the issues of proper camera setup for analogous systems as yours and proper post-analysis to obtain results that are not only consistent but also accurate.